# ControlTemplate doesn't find Resources anymore

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controltemplate, resourcedictionary

I first created a `UserControl`.
In the xaml I can reference `StaticResource`s that are in the main Application's Resources.

I then refactored this `UserControl` to a `Control` and via [Themes/Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232333/1163),
I apply a `ControlTemplate` (I needed [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ea0006d0-d4a8-43b7-94d8-ebf071ae4a40)).

But this way the `StaticResource`s are not found anymore (an `XamlParseException` is thrown at runtime).

I could merge the `ResourceDictionaries` that contain the `StaticResource` I need *also* in the Genericl.xaml file, but I'd like to avoid this due to [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871760/1163)

*What are the mechanics behind this behaviour?*